# MongoDB Doesn't Run

Tags: linux, mongodb, archlinux

I just installed mongoDB with AUR in arch and tried to run it just like;

```
mongod
```

but it always says;

```
2019-05-11T17:07:09.608+0000 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=27076 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=manjaro
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.9
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: fc525e2d9b0e4bceff5c2201457e564362909765
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/data/db", mmapv1: { smallFiles: true } } }
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2019-05-11T17:07:09.612+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-05-11T17:07:09.612+0000 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-05-11T17:07:09.612+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-05-11T17:07:09.612+0000 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
2019-05-11T17:07:09.611+0000 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
```

You're missing a path to it's db directory. Create one in your root folder using:

```
sudo mkdir /data/db
```

sudo recommended here, sometimes mongoDB can run in to permission issues otherwise.